# PSTricks and Lorenz-Curve

Tags: pstricks

So I have some trouble concerning Lorenz-curves and PSTricks.  I've extended the example in pst-func to a MWE:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[latex={-interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape},%
 pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY},%
 pdfcrop={--hires},crop=on]{auto-pst-pdf}

 \usepackage{pst-func}

 \begin{document}
 \centerline{%
 \begin{postscript}
 \psset{lly=-6mm,llx=-5mm} 
 \psgraph[Dx=0.2,Dy=0.2,axesstyle=frame](0,0)(1,1){6cm}{6cm} 
 \psline[linestyle=dashed](1,1) 
 \psLorenz*[linecolor=blue!30,linewidth=1.5pt]{0.50 0.10 0.3 0.09 0.01 } 
 \psLorenz[linecolor=blue!30,plotstyle=bezier]{0.50 0.10 0.3 0.09 0.01 } 
 \psLorenz[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{0.50 0.10 0.3 0.09 0.01 } 
 \endpsgraph
 \end{postscript}}

 \centerline{%
 \begin{postscript}
 \psset{lly=-6mm,llx=-5mm} 
 \psgraph[Dx=0.2,Dy=0.2,axesstyle=frame](0,0)(1,1){6cm}{6cm} 
 \psline[linestyle=dashed](1,1) 
 \psLorenz*[linecolor=blue!30,linewidth=1.5pt]{1 1 1 1 1 } 
 \psLorenz[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{1 1 1 1 1 } 
 \endpsgraph
 \end{postscript}}
 \end{document}
```

The second Lorenz-curve is actually the from (0,0) to (1,1).

[image]

The ordered x-data are 0.01, 0.09, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, hence the distribution is 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0.  So shouldn't  the Lorenz-curve be the polygon through

(0,0), (0.2,0.01), (0.4,0.1), (0.6, 0.2), (0.8,0.5), and (1,1)?

Comment: It would be much easier to try to answer this if you would add a full minimal working example and not just a fragment of a TeX document.

Comment: Yes, that looks buggy, I'll have alook. However, it may be a good idea if you could try your own code first with a full example ...

Answer (score 4):

This is the output for the fixed version of `pst-func` which will be uploaded to CTAN later:

[image]

Comment: Excellent!  That was fast, thank you very much.

Comment: There's still a bug:

     \psLorenz[Gini,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]<.2 .2 .2 .2 .2>{.1 .1 .1 .35 .35 } 

reports correctly 0.3 as Gini-coefficient.  In case you omit the x-data

     \psLorenz[Gini,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt{.1 .1 .1 .35 .35 } 

the coefficient becomes -1.85, which is absurd.

Comment: I see, used wrong variable. Will be fixed ...

Comment: and uploaded to CTAN ...

Comment: Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Unfortunately there's another bug.  The Lorenz-curve for your new example on p. 67: \psLorenz[linewidth=1.5pt,Gini]<83 104 134 143 185>{460 343 406 501 1662}
is \psline[linecolor=red](0,0)(.128,.102)(.288,.222)(.495,.359)(.715,.507)(1,1)

Comment: Where are the wrong values in the excel table: https://towardsdatascience.com/clearly-explained-gini-coefficient-and-lorenz-curve-fe6f5dcdc07. (in the middle of the webpage)

Comment: In the example "Pred" must be sorted from low to high, beginning with 83, 104, and so on.

Comment: Then Gini is also wrong ... Please see http://hvoss.org/pst-func-doc.pdf . Correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me.  -- The Lorenz-curve can't lie over the line through the origin and (1, 1).

Comment: ok, next upload ... :-)

Comment: Thanks for your work and patience.